# SwiftUI attach element of ForEach loop to global position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to attach an element to a (global!) position. Sounds easy, but the element (here: the Circle) is declared in a ScrollView and a ForEach loop. It's essential that the declaration of the Circle stays the same (example is simplified). My goal is that the element doesn't move when the user scrolls through the list.

GIF: The circles are supposed to be on top of each other and they should not move.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var elements = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(elements, id: \.self){ elem in
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                        
                        Text("\(elem)")
                    }

                    // the circle below should stay in the ForEach loop!
                    .overlay(Circle() // <- I tried to use an overlay, but that does not work
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .position(x: 100, y: 100) // <- can't set global position!
                    )
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything inside ScrollView will be scrolled, so why you just don't move circles *out* of ScrollView?

Comment: @Asperi As you may have noticed, I am implementing a custom list. Now I want to implement the reorder functionality by dragging elements up and down. Thus, every entry in the ForEach has a drag button. If the user drags it up, the offset of the entry changes and eventually, the entries in the array swap. However, the position of the drag button changes as well so the new offset is incorrect. My idea was to fix the drag button at the start position if it has been triggered so the offset will be right. If there is no way to do this like in my question, I will have to rethink my approach.

Comment: @Asperi Solved it with a GeometryReader. But I still don't understand why one can't select which coordinate space ```position``` should use.